# (SOLVED) useState Hook won't trigger when i set state in onSelect (using react-bootstrap-table next)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap-table

This is my code using MERN Stack, I noticed that whenever I refresh the page and first click on the checkbox of the table, the state of selected won't change, but it will do set the state after the second click I made, any suggestion please

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([])
const users = [...]
const column = [...]
const selectRow = {
    mode: 'checkbox',
    clickToSelect: true,
    //onSelect event
    onSelect: (row, isSelect, rowIndex, e) => {
        //if the checkbox was checked then add it into the selected array
        //else remove it
        if (isSelect === true) {
            setSelected([...selected, row._id])
            console.log(selected)
        }
        else if (isSelect === false) {
            setSelected(selected.filter(item => item !== row._id))
            console.log(selected)
        }
    },
};
```

[table refreshed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNPmp.png)

[check once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OP0D.png)

[empty result array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyJ45.png)

[check 1 more time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g0ou.png)

[the result shows 1 array item although i checked 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qML5g.png)

Comment: Is this an off by one error? What happens if the first thing you click is the 2nd or 3rd check? Does it give the value of it? Or does it give the value of the 1st or 2nd?

Comment: Use code snippets for descriptions in order to make it easier for us to understand.

Comment: can you create codesandbox or fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

The useState react hook is asynchronous. You won't be able to log `selected` right after changing the state as you will get the current value and not the updated one.

What is happening in your screenshots is

first checkbox clicked

```js
setSelected([...selected, row._id]) //async call to setSelected to update state
console.log(selected) // logging the current value of selected ([])
//...sometime shortly after selected will become (['id of first checkbox'])
```

second checkbox clicked

```js
setSelected(selected.filter(item => item !== row._id)) //async call to setSelected to update state
console.log(selected) // logging the current value of selected (['id of first checkbox'])
//...sometime shortly after selected will become (['id of first checkbox', 'id of second checkbox'])
```

In short, I believe your code is working as intended.

If you put something like the following somewhere inside the rendered jsx of the component you will see your component re-render (almost instantly) with the appropriate ids showing every time you click a checkbox that will show you your coding is working correctly.

```js
{selected.map(id => <p>id</p>)}
```